# Dialog Box to select an image from gallery

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-activity, firebase-storage

I am trying to show a dialog box where ever an ImageButton is pressed, and then choose either pictures from gallery or take some from camera.
 I am already struggling to select an image and insert it into the right image view.

Right now, clicking ImageButton (android:id="@+id/imageSelect") will bring up the dialog box, then select choose from gallery, but it insert the image  into (android:id="@+id/imageSelect1) which should be inserted into (android:id="@+id/imageSelect).
And when I select  (android:id="@+id/imageSelect1) it just overwrite the image, so (android:id="@+id/imageSelect) remains empty

I have a feeling that something is wrong in the SelectPhotoDialog Class.

Doing with without the Dialog box works fine, but I would like to have that option to choose from camera or gallery.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image 1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageSelect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image 2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageSelect1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Image 3" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageSelect2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Title"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_description"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Description"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Price"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_country"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Country"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_state_province"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="State/Province/Region"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="City"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Your Contact Email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:padding="7dp"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="Post"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"/>

    </LinearLayout>


 </ScrollView>

 </FrameLayout>
```

My post fragment file:

```
private void init(){

    mSelectImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog to choose new photo");
            SelectPhotoDialog dialog = new SelectPhotoDialog();
            dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_select_photo));
            dialog.setTargetFragment(PostFragment.this, 1);
        }
    });

    mSelectImage1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: opening dialog to choose new photo");
            SelectPhotoDialog dialog1 = new SelectPhotoDialog();
            dialog1.show(getFragmentManager(), getString(R.string.dialog_select_photo1));
            dialog1.setTargetFragment(PostFragment.this, 2);
        }
    });
```

SelectPhotoDialog file:

```
 @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_selectphoto, container, false);

    TextView selectPhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogChoosePhoto);
    selectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: accessing phones memory.");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });

    TextView selectPhoto1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogChoosePhoto1);

    selectPhoto1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: accessing phones memory.");
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICKFILE_REQUEST_CODE1);
        }
    });

    TextView takePhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogOpenCamera);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting camera.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

Complete PostFragment file:

https://pastebin.com/PJXB3cq1

Complete SelectPhotoDialog

https://pastebin.com/fF2Jj986

IniversalImageLoader file

[Universal image loader](https://pastebin.com/geEGbz0r)

Comment: use this library and your life will be way much simpler https://github.com/jkwiecien/EasyImage

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but i don't think there is enough information... i can't find the `UniversalImageLoader` that is referenced, i imagine that it handles the actual setting of the image, as `setImage` implies.

```
@Override

    public void getImagePath(Uri imagePath) {

        Log.d(TAG, "getImagePath: setting the image to imageview");

       // THIS LINE  UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imagePath.toString(), mSelectImage);

 

        //assign to global variable

        mSelectedBitmap = null;

        mSelectedUri = imagePath;

    }
```

***Update to Answer***
OK, So here's how i usually perform the dialog you are using

```
private static final int READ_REQUEST_CODE = 42;

public void performFileSearch()
{

    // ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT is the intent to choose a file via the system's file
    // browser.
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);

    // Filter to only show results that can be "opened", such as a
    // file (as opposed to a list of contacts or timezones)
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    // Filter to show only images, using the image MIME data type.
    // If one wanted to search for ogg vorbis files, the type would be "audio/ogg".
    // To search for all documents available via installed storage providers,
    // it would be "*/*".
    intent.setType("*/*");

    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData)
{
   if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
       Uri uri = null;
        if (resultData != null)
        {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            String back = uri.toString();
           // DO SOMETHING WITH STRING
        }
    }
}
```

**SO THEN YOUR CODE WOULD BE**

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_selectphoto, container, false);

    TextView selectPhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogChoosePhoto);
    selectPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: accessing phones memory.");
            performFileSearch()
        }
    });

    TextView selectPhoto1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogChoosePhoto1);

    selectPhoto1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: accessing phones memory.");
            performFileSearch();
        }
    });

    TextView takePhoto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dialogOpenCamera);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onClick: starting camera.");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);

        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

// I don't think that this is the cause, just because everything seems to flow through until the part that set's the image... The dialog will return a uri to the image, but another code is setting the image in the wrong place,

```
ImageView X = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ImageViewID); 
X.setBackgroundResource ?
```

Or something similar, is what im looking for, i think it may be causing the problem.

**Scratch that**
I found the ImageLoader, and everything seems ok ..

```
Constructor Detail:

ImageLoader

public ImageLoader(RequestQueue queue, ImageLoader.ImageCache imageCache)Constructs a new ImageLoader.

// Parameters:queue - The RequestQueue to use for making image requests.imageCache - The cache to use as an L1 cache.
```

Have you tried another form of setting the image ?

Comment: I have added that file and some issues I am having

Comment: I replaced uri in onActivityResul, and and image was set correctly, but selecting a second image just overwrite the first one and not setting to the right view. Also, how do I pass the String back  to mOnPhotoSelectedListener.getImagePath(back); it says cannot be applied